# Extending or Wrapping the native Date object

Tags: javascript, date, coffeescript, prototype

I want to write a wrapper around Javascript's native `Date` object type.  For each property native to the date, I'd like to simply proxy that to the date owned by my class.  I'm using coffee script and everything seems to work except any methods that alter the date object.  I'm wondering if I'm setting up the binding incorrectly.

Here is what I have so far.  If you checkout what it comipiles into (modified to play nice with JSLint, but identical behavior as what i'm seeing in-browser) you can see its behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/XRgKM/1/

```
class CP.MyDate

  @DateProperties: (name for name in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window.Date.prototype) when _.isFunction(window.Date.prototype[name]))

  constructor: (@date = new Date()) ->
    # Hack to allow me to use the __bind function like the rest of the
    # 'coffeescript native' class functions:
    bnd = `__bind`
    for name in MyDate.DateProperties
      bnd(@[name], @)

    # Validate parameter:
    if not @date instanceof Date
      throw new Error("date must be a native date")

    # Copy date locally:
    @date = new Date(@date)

  test: () => alert("TEST")

  for name in @DateProperties
    MyDate.prototype[name] = () ->
      returnVal = @date[name].apply(@date, arguments)
      if returnVal isnt @date and returnVal instanceof Date
        returnVal = new MyDate(returnVal)
      return returnVal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the standard *closure inside a loop* problem. What do you think `name` will be inside the functions in here?

```
for name in @DateProperties
  MyDate.prototype[name] = () ->
    returnVal = @date[name].apply(@date, arguments)
    if returnVal isnt @date and returnVal instanceof Date
      returnVal = new MyDate(returnVal)
    return returnVal
```

Inside the functions, `name` will be the last value of `@DateProperties` and that's nothing at all like what you want. You need to get the current value of `name` into the functions rather than the `name` references. Since this is such a common thing, CoffeeScript has the [`do` keyword](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) to help:

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

You want to do this:

```
for name in @DateProperties
  do (name) ->
    # Carry on as before...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8gc7b/

Also note that jsfiddle supports CoffeeScript, look under *Panels* in the sidebar.

And you don't need to make `DateProperties` visible like that, you could hide it:

```
class CP.MyDate

  DateProperties = (name for name in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window.Date.prototype) when _.isFunction(window.Date.prototype[name]))
```

and refer to just `DateProperties` inside your `CP.MyDate` class.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel a bit dumb.  I'm pretty sure I've answered this exact question in other languages before....